# Not copying string from file to linked list parameter

Tags: c

```
void read_names(ex6 **first)
{
    FILE *fltext;
    ex6 *next;
    char aux[50];
    next = malloc(sizeof(ex6));
    if (!next)
        return;
    (*first) = next;
    fltext = fopen(nome_fich_6a, "rt");
    if (!fltext)
        return;
    while (!feof(fltext)) {
        fscanf(fltext, "%[^\n]s\n", aux);
        next->name = malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(aux));
        if (!prox->name)
            return;
        strcpy(next->name, aux);
        while (next->prox != NULL)
            next = next->prox;
    }
    fclose(fltext);
}
```

So I'm doing this exercise and when I try to read the content of the string saved in text file, it just returns to the menu and does not read any content into the next->name parameter. If anyone could help me tackle this error I would really apreciate it.

So this are the changes I made to the code

```
void read_names(ex6 **first)
{
    FILE *fltext;
    ex6 *next;
    char aux[50];
    next = malloc(sizeof(ex6));
    if (!next)
        return;
    (*first) = next;
    fltext = fopen(nome_fich_6a, "rt");
    if (!fltext)
        return;
    while (fgets(aux, 50, fltext)) {
        next->name = malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(aux));
        if (!prox->name)
            return;
        sscanf(aux, "%[^\n]s", next->name);
        strcpy(next->name, aux);
        while (next->prox != NULL)
            next = next->prox;
    }
    fclose(fltext);
}
```

Comment: Thank! Already did and made some changes to the code itself after a brief moment of time trying understand what I was doing wrong I though of using the fgets() function and the sscanf(). So here are the changes I made to the code (this method works just fine on a test program I made but still seems to be under stress when executed on the exercise I'm trying to solve...

Comment: are you trying to make a list?

Comment: yes, I am that's what I think to be the problem... when I try to read the content of the file into the list it just crashes... still I think I should have done next->othervar = NULL in order to make sure it didn't go full retard on me

Comment: @JoãoRodriguesJR: Just a note, I added a `)` to this line         `while (fgets(aux, 50, fltext)) {` of your question because it was missing one that would prevent compilation.

Answer (score 0):

Look, beside of : `malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(aux));` you are allocating the sizof string without '\0' so you should allocate 1 more for example `malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(aux) + 1);`. When you are copying the `aux` you are writing over the next segment of memory you didn't allocate. Next, there is no link between nodes. That is why

```
while (next->prox != NULL)
                next = next->prox;
```

fails. Try to make a links inside of while loop and that should work. And i hope you made the `name` variable as `char *`

In while loop, you are missing ')'.

Comment: First of all sorry for only replying now, I've been very busy!
Second yes I've made Variable name a char * because if I didn't oh boy I would be like Jon Snow (xD) and I've already done that on the malloc statement spotted that one on the day I've posted this topic. I'm still not able to figure out why this is failing but this a exxercise I was doing to study for an exame I had the very next day and guess what!
A question just like this one came out on the very first one... thankfully I knew that when I used the exact same method on another file it worked just fine...

Comment: Anyways Thank tou very much for your help and I'm still gonna try and figure out that's happening

Comment: The point is you should be creating links inside of the while loop. You are not making any link to the new node. Take care of that.